# Using Math.Net Numerics, how to find a curve fitting for "Power"

Tags: c#, math, curve-fitting, pow

I'm trying to reproduce same curve fitting (called "trending") in Excel but in  C#: Exponential, Linear, Logarithmic, Polynomial and Power.

I found linear and polynomial as :

```
Tuple<double, double> line = Fit.Line(xdata, ydata); 
double[] poly2 = Fit.Polynomial(xdata, ydata, 2);
```

I also found [Exponential fit](https://discuss.mathdotnet.com/t/exponential-fit/131).

But I wonder how to do curve fitting for Power. Anybody has an idea?

I should be able to get both constants like shown into the Excel screen shot formula:

- power
- multiplier (before x)

[image]

Comment: IIRC, it's doing a least squares regression against `y = c*(x^b)`, where it finds the values of `c, b` that minimize the regression.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before anybody would be the fifth who vote to close this question...

I asked the question directly to the forum of mathdotnet (that I recently discovered). Christoph Ruegg, the main developper of the lib, answered me something excellent that I want to share in order to help other with the same problem:

> Assuming with power you’re referring to a target function along the
>   lines of y : x -> a*x^b, then this is a simpler version of what I’ve
>   described in [Linearizing non-linear models by transformation.](https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/Regression.html#Linearizing-non-linear-models-by-transformation)
>
> This seems to be used often enough so I’ve started to add a new
>   Fit.Power and Fit.Exponential locally for this case - not pushed yet
>   since it first needs more testing, but I expect it to be part of v4.1.
>
> Alternatively, by now we also support non-linear optimization which
>   could also be used for use cases like this (FindMinimum module).

Link to my question: [mathdonet - Curve fitting: Power](https://discuss.mathdotnet.com/t/curve-fitting-power/605)